# How we can I get all credentials from jenkins as an environment variables?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get all credentials using `credentials()`, stored in the folder. But due to interpolation and masking issues, those credentials are visible on UI, which is not secure. So, is there any way where I can load all the credentials?